# 5 or 6 - Written vs Oral Torah (Z"A vs Malchus)

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, mishna, pentateuch-chumash

*This question is intended only for those familiar with some basic Kabbalistic concepts*.

As we know (from יהו"ה), that ו (Vav, number 6) stands for Z"A (masculine) and ה (He, number 5) stands for Malchus (feminine).

However, the Written Torah - that is Z"A - has 5 books, where the Oral Torah - that's Malchus - has 6 Sdarim.

How come?

---

Related: ["why-is-the-torah-divided-into-five-books"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97966/why-is-the-torah-divided-into-five-books)

Related: ["why-masculine-nouns-agree-with-feminine-numbers"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86405/why-in-hebrew-masculine-nouns-agree-with-feminine-numbers-and-vice-verse)

Comment: And yud (10) is chochma and the first hei is binah

Comment: @Al Berko The written Torah is also divided into 7 books (meaning 6 pratim and the whole, 1, for a total of 7) according to one tradition. In the context of your question, it emphasizes for both the Written Torah and the Oral Torah (the six orders of the Mishnah correspond to the 5 Gevurot, which correspond to the 5 parts of the mouth as in Oral Torah, and the whole, 1, for a total of 6), That the proper perspective is in regard to concept that both the written and oral Torah are one.

Comment: @Al Berko And if the significance of the written Torah (the Ratzon HaElyon) being divided into 7 books (6 plus 1) isn't understood, this corresponds to the union of the two names related to masculine and feminine (יהוה אהיה אהיהוה).

Comment: @Al Berko And just to emphasize, this concept of Klal and Prat, Whole and Individual, is the concept emphasized in the parshiyot of VaYakhel and Pekudei.